# Do $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are the actual bounds of a sequence?

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

Can you say that $\limsup a_n$ is the upper bound of the sequence $a_n$ and $\liminf a_n$ is the lower bound of $a_n$?

Comment: Consider the sequence $5+1, 3-1, 5+1/2, 3-1/2, 5+1/3, 3-1/3...$. The limsup is $5$ and yet the upper bound is $6$. Similarly the liminf is $3$, and yet the lower bound is $2$

Comment: Not necessarily.  Consider the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$.  Note that the $\limsup x_n=\liminf x_n=\lim x_n=0$, but for $x_1>\limsup x_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

If $a_n=(-1)^n + \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, then

1. the upper bound of the sequence is $\frac{3}{2}$
2. the lower bound for the sequence is $-2$
3. $\limsup a_n = 1$
4. $\liminf a_n = -1$

so you have a case when the $\limsup$ is not the upper bound, and the $\liminf$ is not the lower bound.

Comment: mm and what If An->INFINITY or An->-INFINITY

Comment: @TheAsker I suggest you give it a little thought first. What do *you* think happens then?

Comment: @TheAsker Also, please read the following before writing mathematical equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: If An->INFINITY than limsupAn->INFINITY but you already proved I was wrong once ><

Comment: @TheAsker $\limsup a_n \to\infty$ is not the correct way to write it. It's $\limsup a_n = \infty$. But yes, you are correct, if $a_n$ diverges to $\infty$, then $\limsup a_n=\infty$. But I don't see what that has to do with the original question. Also, please use mathjax.